# Interfaces - method returning object of type of the concrete class implementing it

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

Consider a class:

```
// partial code for this class
abstract class DataNode : System.IComparable<DataNode>, System.IEquatable<DataNode>, System.Collections.IEnumerable, IDataNode
{
    protected DataNode parent;
    protected int order = System.Int32.MaxValue;

    // ctor
    protected DataNode(DataNode parent, string name)
    {
       modified = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
       original = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
       _parent = parent;
       if (name == null)
       {
           throw new System.ArgumentNullException("name");
       }
       original.Add("name", name);
       _status = Modification_Status.ADDED;
    }

    // methods returning objects of the same type as the class, need to be defined in interface
    public DataNode getParent()
    {
        // return the parent
    }

    public abstract DataNode deepCopy(DataNode parent);
}
```

A problem arises when dealing with methods in the class implementing this interface that return objects of the same type as the class, as in the two examples above.

The code is in the process of being refactored for unit testing purposes. Part of this is to create interfaces for base classes, such as this one. An interface is being created as follows:

```
// partial interface code
public interface IDataNode
{
    // all public methods

    IData_Node deepCopy(IDataNode parent);
    IData_Node getParent();
}
```

The methods cannot be declared with `DataNode` in the interface, as the return type is less accessible. How to deal with this problem?

Edit: Actually, declaring the `deep_copy` method with return type and parameter both `IDataNode` instead of `DataNode` works, but it seems all references to this in the code need to be changed.

Comment: Whats wrong with `IDataNode` why cant you use that ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall I ended up using `IDataNode` in the `DataNode` base class, and then just updating the references to those methods to the concrete types, if that makes sense. I think it is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to do this is like this:

```
public interface IDataNode
{

}

public interface IDataNode<T> : IDataNode where T : IDataNode
{
    T deepCopy(T parent);
    T getParent();
}

abstract class DataNode : IDataNode<DataNode>
{
    public abstract DataNode deepCopy(DataNode parent);

    public DataNode getParent()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```